# react native calendars change Agenda calendar behaviour

Tags: react-native, calendar

I'm using [React-native](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars) and want tomake some changes in Agenda

1. to show only the items of select day. when scrolling, it will not show the items on next day, so I need also disable move to other day when scroll.
2. show the items in horizontal.
   Im looking to make this example (photo taken from dribbble),
   when press on select day it will show the times of this day.

this example of Agenda from react-native-calendar

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';
import {Agenda} from 'react-native-calendars';

export default class AgendaScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: {}
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Agenda
        items={this.state.items}
        loadItemsForMonth={this.loadItems.bind(this)}
        selected={'2017-05-16'}
        renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
        renderEmptyDate={this.renderEmptyDate.bind(this)}
        rowHasChanged={this.rowHasChanged.bind(this)}
        // markingType={'period'}
        // markedDates={{
        //    '2017-05-08': {textColor: '#666'},
        //    '2017-05-09': {textColor: '#666'},
        //    '2017-05-14': {startingDay: true, endingDay: true, color: 'blue'},
        //    '2017-05-21': {startingDay: true, color: 'blue'},
        //    '2017-05-22': {endingDay: true, color: 'gray'},
        //    '2017-05-24': {startingDay: true, color: 'gray'},
        //    '2017-05-25': {color: 'gray'},
        //    '2017-05-26': {endingDay: true, color: 'gray'}}}
         // monthFormat={'yyyy'}
         // theme={{calendarBackground: 'red', agendaKnobColor: 'green'}}
        //renderDay={(day, item) => (<Text>{day ? day.day: 'item'}</Text>)}
      />
    );
  }

  loadItems(day) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      for (let i = -15; i < 85; i++) {
        const time = day.timestamp + i * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        const strTime = this.timeToString(time);
        if (!this.state.items[strTime]) {
          this.state.items[strTime] = [];
          const numItems = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
          for (let j = 0; j < numItems; j++) {
            this.state.items[strTime].push({
              name: 'Item for ' + strTime,
              height: Math.max(50, Math.floor(Math.random() * 150))
            });
          }
        }
      }
      //console.log(this.state.items);
      const newItems = {};
      Object.keys(this.state.items).forEach(key => {newItems[key] = this.state.items[key];});
      this.setState({
        items: newItems
      });
    }, 1000);
    // console.log(`Load Items for ${day.year}-${day.month}`);
  }

  renderItem(item) {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.item, {height: item.height}]}><Text>{item.name}</Text></View>
    );
  }

  renderEmptyDate() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.emptyDate}><Text>This is empty date!</Text></View>
    );
  }

  rowHasChanged(r1, r2) {
    return r1.name !== r2.name;
  }

  timeToString(time) {
    const date = new Date(time);
    return date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    flex: 1,
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    marginTop: 17
  },
  emptyDate: {
    height: 15,
    flex:1,
    paddingTop: 30
  }
});
```

[image: code above]

I want to change it to be like that[image: photo taken from dribble]

Comment: Did you have any success in doing this, I was planning on doing something similar

Comment: @yamanshrestha no with this calendar. I did weekly dates that comes from server and each date has his own times

Comment: @Manspof please tell us how, i'm actually working on a project with this calendar component, if is not possible to do this, i'm in serious trouble lol